# Laravel update not working or not routing

Tags: php, database, laravel

I made an update form in laravel project to update some entries in my database but when i press submit button nothing is happening.i don't know why.tried everything.
here is the form:

```
<form action="{{ route('loans.update', $loan->id)}}" method="patch">
    <p class="al-left">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" value="{{$loan->data}}" id="date">
    </p>

    <p class="al-left">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$loan->nume}}" id="name">
    </p>

    <p class="al-left">
        <label for="period">Period(months):</label>
        <input type="number" name="period" value="{{$loan->durata}}" id="period">
    </p>

    <p class="al-left">
        <label for="month">Month Rate(euro):</label>
        <input type="number" name="month" value="{{$loan->valoare_rata_luna}}" id="month">
    </p>

    <p class="al-left">
        <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
        <input type="number" name="amount" value="{{$loan->valoare_totala}}" id="amount">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="submit" value="Edit">
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
```

here is the delete function in controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

    $id = Auth::id();
    $loan =loan::find($id);

    $loan->cod_user=$id;
    $loan->nume = $request->name;
    $loan->data=$request->date;
    $loan->durata=$request->period;
    $loan->valoare_rata_luna=$request->month;
    $loan->valoare_totala=$request->amount;
    $loan->save();
    return view("loans")->with('loans', $loans);
}
```

the routes:

```
Route::resource('/finance/loans','loanController');
```

To say that form action is in loans.blade.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Form only supports `GET` and `POST` method. You have spoof the 'PATCH` method like:

```
<form action="{{ route('loans.update', $loan->id)}}" method="POST">  //**Here method = POST
    <p class="al-left">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }} //**Here give PATCH by spoofing method
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" value="{{$loan->data}}" id="date">
    </p>
    ..
    ..
    ..

</form>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```html
Route web.php
Route::resource('loans', 'LoansController');

<form action="{{ route('loans.update', $loan->id)}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
</form>
```